# Docker with tensorflow, pytorch, gdal, and jupyter notebook

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, gdal

So I got a Docker working with tensorflow, pytorch, gdal, and jupyter notebook using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter

USER root

# install base utilities
RUN apt update && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y gcc

# install gdal
RUN apt-get install -y gdal-bin
RUN apt-get install -y libgdal-dev
RUN export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y wget

# install miniconda
ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh

# put conda in path so we can use conda activate
ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/

# upgrade pip and install python libraries
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install tensorflow
RUN pip3 install tensorflow_hub tensorflow_datasets
RUN pip3 install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version) --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal"
RUN pip3 install numpy matplotlib boto3 rasterio shapely scikit-learn scikit-image
RUN pip3 install torch==1.7.1+cu110 torchvision==0.8.2+cu110 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I got a warning saying not to install things as root. Is there a way to get this to work with USER jovyan?

Also, when I used docker compose to build it, I wasn't able to find any of my volumes until I mounted things to /home/mydirectory:/tf. Why does it need to mount to /tf? Is there a way to change that cleanly or am I stuck with that because of the base docker that was used?

Answer (score 0):

I built an image for environment integrating cuda, conda, jupyter, ssh, pytorch and tensorflow. You can refer to it [GitHub](https://github.com/xuan-wei/nvidia-pytorch-tensorflow-conda-jupyter-ssh) and change it accordingly.

I created a new root user called sjtu. It avoids many problems. Also, conda allows new environment flexibly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).